# How to add outgoing payment on account in PHP, SAP B1?

Tags: php, sapb1

I know how to add outgoing or incoming payment with Invoices in PHP it works fine, but I tried to add outgoing payment on account it does not work, below is my codes I tried to do I do know if there is something I forget

```
$oIncoming=$mycomp->GetBusinessObject(46);
$oIncoming->CardCode="303000";
$oIncoming->DocDate="2019-02-07";
$oIncoming->TaxDate="2019-02-07";
$oIncoming->BPLId=4;
$oIncoming->Series=78;

$oIncoming->CashSum=1000;
$oIncoming->CashAccount="561100";

$oIncoming->AccountPayments->AccountCode = "303000";
$oIncoming->AccountPayments->SumPaid = 1000;
$oIncoming->AccountPayments->OcrCode="AB";
$RetCode=$oIncoming->AccountPayments->Add;

$RetCode=$oIncoming->Add;
if ($RetCode==0)
{
echo"Added";
}
else
{
echo"Not added";
}
```

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Please remove the Java tag.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? Why does this question have the [tag:java] tag? Adding unrelated programming tags *will* increase attention to your question, but as it will annoy experts in a field who are erroneously drawn to your question, it may be negative attention, attention that you don't want to attract.

Comment: I've removed the tag, please let me know if I have done this in error and why